# Define bbox for two different maps

Tags: r

I have two different datasets:

```
library(tidycensus)
wp <- get_acs(geography = "tract", variable = "B02001_002",
                state = "NY",  county= "New York", geometry = TRUE, year = 2020)

bp <- get_acs(geography = "tract", variable = "B03002_004",
                state = "NY",  county= "New York", geometry = TRUE, year = 2020)
```

I would like to create a map, but I got this error message

```
bbox_w <- st_bbox(wp)
xrange <- bbox_w$xmax - bbox_w$xmin
yrange <- bbox_w$ymax - bbox_w$ymin
bbox_w[1] <- bbox_w[1] - (0.065 * xrange)
bbox_w[4] <- bbox_w[4] + (0.065 * yrange)
bbox_w <- bbox_w %>% 
  st_as_sfc()

bbox_b <- st_bbox(bp)
xrange <- bbox_b$xmax - bbox_b$xmin
yrange <- bbox_b$ymax - bbox_b$ymin
bbox_b[1] <- bbox_b[1] - (0.065 * xrange)
bbox_b[4] <- bbox_b[4] + (0.065 * yrange)
bbox_b <- bbox_b %>% 
  st_as_sfc()

white<-tm_shape(wp,bbox_w) + tm_fill("estimate")
black<-tm_shape(bp,bbox_b) + tm_fill("estimate")

tmap_arrange(white,black)
```

I want the maps next to each other, and same bbox for both maps, but got this

```
Error in vapply(g, function(i) i[[1]], character(1)) : values must be type 'character', but FUN(X[[2]]) result is type 'list'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where does the `get_acs` function come from? You should always list the packages you use in your code, preferably as `library(xyz)` in your text. I think its some census package from what I remember of an earlier Q of yours (or maybe someone else) but you should expect anyone seeing a Q to come to it "cold". You also seem to be using `sf` and `tmap`, so you should add them too.

Comment: I use another dataset, but can not share it, but I recently saw another example here in stackoverflow, and according to them it must be tidycensus

Comment: get_acs is a good example to have a dataset to share, but what I use it another dataset, but I correct it now

Comment: The most convenient sample data sets can be the ones that come with `sf` and don't need a download, for example the North Carolina data set, `nc`, you can see when you do `example(st_read)` which is created via: `nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always try and test the steps you are taking to find where the problem first occurs. In this case I discovered the two maps, `black` and `white` are already broken so the `tmap_arrange` isn't going to work:

```
> black<-tm_shape(bp,bbox_b) + tm_fill("estimate")
> black
Error in vapply(g, function(i) i[[1]], character(1)) : 
  values must be type 'character',
 but FUN(X[[2]]) result is type 'list'
```

So something is wrong with your construction of a simple tmap there. Let's see. How does `tm_shape` know you want that second argument to be the bounding box? Let's look at the help:

```
Usage:
     tm_shape(
       shp,
       name = NULL,
       is.master = NA,
       projection = NULL,
       bbox = NULL,
       unit = NULL,
```

oh, it doesn't think the second argument is the bbox, it thinks its the name. To specify the bbox, unless you also specify the args before it, you need to name the argument:

```
> black<-tm_shape(bp, bbox=bbox_b) + tm_fill("estimate")
> white<-tm_shape(wp, bbox=bbox_w) + tm_fill("estimate")
> tmap_arrange(black, white)
```

[image]